# Получение ID последнего добавленного елемента

Tags: mysql

Как получить id последнего добавленного елемента? Нашел следующую конструкцию `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()` НО на сколько она безопасна?

Если я сначала делаю `INSERT INTO table` а потом выполняю `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()`есть вероятность того что в этот в же момент "кто-то" добавил еще одну запись и мне вернется не тот `id`? Или может можно(нужно) объеденить это в один запрос типа `INSERT INTO section (section_name) VALUES('bob') SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()`- только это синтаксическин не правельная операция...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Функция **LAST_INSERT_ID** работает независимо от запросов других клиентов. Это значит, что значение, возвращаемое функцией **LAST_INSERT_ID** для отдельного клиента, является значением, сгенерированным только этим клиентом. Благодаря этому каждый пользователь получает свой собственный уникальный идентификатор.

Важно отметить, что если вставить несколько строк в таблицу с помощью одного оператора INSERT, то функция **LAST_INSERT_ID** вернет идентификатор первой вставленной строки.

Comment: Если не затруднит, что есть "клиент"? Другой коннекшен? То есть все работает в пределах одного конекшена? Я могу выполнять в разных конекшенах разные стейтменты и в каждом отдельном коннекше результат `LAST_INSERT_ID` будет разный?

Comment: @BogdanShulga совершенно верно, операция работает в пределах сессии клиента установившего соединение.

Comment: Благодарствую.)